# How to add list of objects in c#

Tags: c#, list, object

I have a user that has multiple cars. I need to create a list of object of all the properties of all his cars.

His CarTable

```
UserID   UserCarID
 101       C101
 101       C102
 101       C103
```

His Car Properties Table

```
UserCarID   Model  Year  Color
C101        Audi   2012  Black
C102        BMW    2012  Silver
C103        VW     2012  White
C104        Audi   2013  Black
C105        VW     2013  White
```

I want a list so that only his list of cars shows up

```
UserID UserCarID   Model  Year  Color
101    C101        Audi   2012  Black
101    C102        BMW    2012  Silver
101    C103        VW     2012  White
```

I tried

```
using (SqlConnection con = .....)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM CarTable Where UserID = @ID";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", UserID));

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= tempID.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        tempID[i] = -1;
                    }
                    int j = 0;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        tempID[j] = (int)reader["ID"];
                        j++;
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
            con.Close();

        }
        foreach (int carID in tempID)
        {
            if (carID > -1) return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getAllCars(carID));
        }

        public static object getAllCars(int id){
            .........
            return carPropertiesObject;
        }
```

getAllCars returns a list of all the properties of Car.
This works, but I only get properties of C101. How would I go about doing this? thank you

Comment: Return will exit out of the method on the first result, exiting out of the foreach loop.

Comment: thanks you actkatiemacias... I figured that since I only get first set of data. How would I add the remaining set of datas from getAllCars()

Comment: What is `tempID`? It's used on a lot of lines of your code, but you don't define it anywhere...

Comment: Abe... it's defined gloabally, it's an array that stores all UserCarID from car table

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mattias, but my objective here is to create a list of object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear on your exact question, but I'll give it a shot:

Seems like a good time to create a Car class:

```
class Car
{
    int UserID;
    int UserCarID;
    string Model; 
    int Year;  
    string Color;
}
```

then

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
while(reader.read())
{
     Car newCar = new Car();
     newCar.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserId"]); //Should probably use TryParse here, but I will use ToInt32 for simplicity sake
     //same for other columns
     cars.Add(newCar);
}
```

The method you are using to process the results of your query looks very strange to me.  Is there some specific reason you are doing it like this?

Comment: Thanks Abe... I am getting the carTable from a stored procedure. I just put the sql query to make the method more meaningful... I will try your solution...

Comment: :)... so silly I am... thank you so much Abe... worked like a charm... I am really new to c#... didn't occur to me to use class instead of using an array... thanks ya'll

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear.  This appears to be an SQL querying issue, not a list joining issue.

Assuming these are both tables in SQL Server, you can get your results from the database with a single query:

```
Select * FROM CarTable, CarPropertiesTable
WHERE CarTable.UserId = CarPropertiesTable.UserId
AND CarTable.UserId = @ID
```

Just then iterate over the DataRows returned and convert them to your objects (see the other answer about creating a Car class, a very good idea), then serialize them to JSON.

Comment: Thank you Jason... the problem with my situation is I get the CarTable from a Stored Procedure...so I really can't just use sql queries